# Is there a straight forward way to transform the s.e. of the cumulative hazard into the s.e. of survival?

Tags: standard-error, cox-model

The `R` function `survival::survfit` returns under `$std.err` the standard error of the cumulative hazard. Using the log or log-log transformation the confidence level can be estimated if one has the standard errors of the survival predictions, but the standard error of the cumulative hazard is given.

Is there a way to transform the s.e. of the cumulative hazard into the s.e. of survival? Clearly, $\Lambda=-\exp(S)$ so $V(\Lambda)=V(\exp(S))$, but how to go on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the delta method. The univariate delta method tells us that if

$(\hat \theta - \theta) / \sqrt n  \rightarrow_d N(0,\sigma^2)$

then

$(f(\hat \theta) - f(\theta) )/ \sqrt n \rightarrow_d N(0,  f'(\theta)^2\sigma^2) $.

In our case, we have that $S(t) = \exp(-H(t))$, so if $\hat H$ is an estimate cumulative hazard value with standard error $s_h$, then we get standard that the standard error for the survival is

$s_s = \sqrt{s_h^2 (-\exp(-H)^2)} = s_h \exp(-H) = S * s_h $

where $S = \exp(-H)$ (i.e. the corresponding survival value).

With that said, I would suspect that a Wald CI built on the cumulative hazards scale and then transformed to the survival scale would actually provide better small sample coverage than a CI built from using the SE provided by the delta method on the survival scale and building a Wald CI from that.